# WP7 text box background colour when selected

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a very simple WP7 app just for fun.  I've got a textbox on my view and when I click it the background colour changes to white.  As the text foreground is also white, the text doesn't show.  Is there a way of overriding this default styling?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Short answer yes, but the issue is down to the fact that you've overridden part of the UI. Can you post the XAML please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood question correctly, you can change background and foreground brush of the TextBox on GotFocus event, like this:

```
 private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      textBox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
      textBox1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
 }
```

Comment: hi if i want to put the same style to different textboxes like above what should i do?

Comment: i have around 5 textboxes in my xaml page i want to set the style for all the textboxes